# When person joins with nickname IRC

Tags: javascript, node.js, irc

I am making an IRC bot
I want to make a thing that whenever someone joins the IRC channel with a specific nickname, it will welcome them and say they're a confirmed channel host user and give them ops. But I have no idea what I could do to do this.

I'm using node.js with the **irc** library.

I have tried:

```
bot.addListener("join", function(channel, who) {
    if((who|user|client).(nick|nickname) = "SlimeDiamond", "JS", "Super" { // The things in the brackets separated by the | are what I have tried there.
bot.say("Welcome, " + who + "!"
} else {
return;
});
```

Comment: Is `(who|user|client).(nick|nickname)` suppose to be the nickname ? Also using Nickname in IRC for giving @ access is a very big no no! Maybe you want to use some kind of a specific host mask for op access ? So you will need to give a specific example of how to identify which user deserve @ access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Compare with `==` or `===` not with `=`

Your conditions needs to be something like `if (who.nickname === "Something")`

#### 2. Use `indexOf` if you want to check multiple values

You can't do `if (someVariable == "value1", "value2", "value3")` : you need to do
`if (["value1", "value2", "value3"].indexOf(someVariable) !== -1)`

[Documentation for indexOf here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/indexOf)

so, so far we have `if (["SlimeDiamond", "JS", "Super"].indexOf(who.nickname) !== -1)` for the condition

#### 3. Read the docs

From the [documentation here](https://node-irc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API.html#'join'), the `join` event can be listened to with a callback that takes these three arguments :

- channel
- nickname
- message

I didn't test but it seems that your second argument (`who`) here IS the nickname not an object that contains the nickname. So this should work :

```
bot.addListener("join", function(channel, who) {
    if(["SlimeDiamond", "JS", "Super"].indexOf(who) !== -1) {
        bot.say("Welcome, " + who + "!");
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, so I changed the if to indexOf. And I was using **==**, but I obviously had made a typo when typing the code into stackoverflow. I am using the **irc** library.

Comment: Okay, so you can update your question to add this information (makes it easier for anyone searching the web for the same issue), I will update my answer now